# Запись данных в файл json NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, fs

с помощью fetch я отправляю на сервер json данные "{...}", у меня есть файл db.json

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "text":"test"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "text":"test2"
  }
]
```

Как мне полученный json с помощью fetch записать внутрь [] в db.json файл? я пробовал через fs.write но он перезаписывает файл.

Comment: Боюсь, вам придётся читать файл, парсить его в объект, обновлять объект и с новым объектом перезаписывать файл. Возможно, меня поправят.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt рабочий метод, но можно проще, поправлю XD

Answer (score -1):

**fs.appendFile()/fs.appendFileSync():**

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.appendFileSync("hello.txt", "Привет ми ми ми!");

fs.appendFile("hello.txt", "Привет МИД!", function(error){
    if(error) throw error; // если возникла ошибка

    console.log("Запись файла завершена. Содержимое файла:");
    let data = fs.readFileSync("hello.txt", "utf8");
    console.log(data);  // выводим считанные данные
});
```

[image: fs.appendFile]

@Лукас, это первый запрос в гугл. Может пора становиться самостоятельнее?

```
const fs = require('fs');

const data = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 't'
}, {
    id: 2,
    text: 't2'
}];

// создаём файл
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(data));

// берём старые данные
const dbData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json', (err, data) => (data)))

// сливает данные
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify([...dbData, ...data]));

// читаем файл
const text = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8');
console.log(JSON.parse(text));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема только в том, что JSON так записать нельзя, он получится невалидным.

Comment: ЧТО??? ПРОСТИТЕ? `var json = JSON.stringify(['search result: ' + currentSearchResult);  fs.writeFile("results.json", json);` и на выходе ты получаешь `{
    "search result: currentSearchResult"
}`

Comment: Вариант с добавлением `fs.appendFile("results.json", json , function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
});`

Comment: а теперь попробуйте распарсить получившийся после добавления файл как json

Comment: @Alexey Ten вы серьезно? `fs.readFile('results.json', function (err, data) {
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
})`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alexeyten/853b8e7bf30cfae2ab821dd9f89fb4da

Comment: `const fs = require('fs');

const data = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 't'
}, {
    id: 2,
    text: 't2'
}];

// создаём файл
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(data));

// берём старые данные
const dbData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json', (err, data) => (data)))

// сливает данные
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify([...dbData, ...data]));

// читаем файл
const text = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8');
console.log(JSON.parse(text));
` Вы же пытаетесь 2 массива засунуть в json, понятно это не сработает, попробуйте вот так.

Comment: `[{"id":1,"text":"t"},{"id":2,"text":"t2"},{"id":1,"text":"t"},{"id":2,"text":"t2"}]` - результат

Comment: Так автор же именно что хочет *дописать* в файл в котором уже есть массив. И ваш ответ именно тупо дописывает в файл.

Comment: "Так автор же именно что хочет дописать.", "И ваш ответ именно тупо дописывает в файл." Ну а что не так? Да это немного тупо, потому что в продакшэне так точно никто делать не будет, да и подход немного странные, но что бы не разворачивать базу данных вполне рабочий. Если хотите массив в массиве, не проблема, хотите записать один объект, тоже не проблема, хотите именно appendFileSync, да пожалуйста. Всё ограничено только фантазией.

Comment: Ещё раз: автор хочет дописать данные в файл, очевидно ожидая что в файле после этого будет валидный json. Код в этом ответе в результате даёт невалидный файл. Следовательно это неверный ответ.

Comment: @Alexey Tes специально для вас поправил